# Customise the email body of with approve\Reject options conditions for SharePoint list 2013\Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, flow

Dear SharePoint experts,

On SharePoint list(2013\Online), when user submitted an item, Approver will get an email notification for approving item by workflow process. For getting approvals email, we need approval task workflow. But instead of approval workflow, we are using "Send email" action workflow. So when user add item, email notification will sent to approver for approving the item. Here we need to customise the body of email. We added two name's as Approve & Reject on the email body using html code. Now, we need to achieve that when user click on "Approve text", item need to be approve and go next stage (or) when user click on "Reject text" item need to reject.

How to add "approve\reject" conditions(workflow task conditions) for those. Any-help highly appreciates.

**Note** : We are not using buttons.

Any other approach for achieving below email body, can also suggest us.

Please refer attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SharePoint Online, you can use **Power Automate** to create the approval process and customize the email body as your requirement.

The result will be like:
[image]

More information about how to create an approval process using Power Automate, refer to [Create a flow to manage project approvals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/sharepoint-scenario-approval-flow)